# Faites-vous la liaison dans "fort aimable"?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

Cela sonne mieux à mes oreilles sans la liaison. J'ai grandi en région Parisienne pour référence.

Comment: Je ne ferais probablement pas cette liaison facultative. En revanche, comme on me l'a enseigné, je fais la liaison dans « Vous chantiez, j'en suis **fort aise**… »

Comment: L'expression étant un tantinet châtiée, je la ferais, avec un trait d'ironie entendue ou pas... On la fait dans *trop aimable* que vous pourriez peut-être utiliser. Sinon, je dirais, *c'est sympa*, *c'est cool* :)

Comment: Le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle, mais j'ai trouvé cette page qui dit que c'est facultative: http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/liaison.html

Comment: Merci. Bonne remarque quant à "fort aise" et "trop aimable": je fais la liaison aussi. Et merci pour le lien, @sumelic. Je ne sais pas qui est l'auteur mais ce site regorge d'articles sur les subtilités du français: http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites.html Existe-t'il une référence officielle pour ces questions de liaisons? Une publication de l'académie, ou que sais-je?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Oui la liaison doit être faite, je ne vois rien qui indique qu'elle est facultative. La page http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue de l'académie française indique clairement :

> La liaison est obligatoire entre l’adverbe et le mot unis étroitement (...). La liaison (...) ne se pratique pas (...) après les mots terminés en -rt (...) sauf (...) s’il s’agit du t de l’adverbe fort

D'autres sources néanmoins (voir la réponse de Laure ci-dessous) affirment le contraire et il est vrai que si fort aimable sonne mieux avec le son `t`, "fort intéressant" sonne bien avec le son `r`, le `t` semblant correspondre à un niveau de langage plus soutenu.

Comment: Tout ce que cette citation affirme c'est que la liaison après *fort* n'est pas obligatoire (elle ne l'est en effet pas). Il n'en découle pas qu'elle soit obligatoire. Sans mentionner que l'Académie appelle obligatoire des liaisons qui ne le sont pas, comme après *est* ou après les prépositions monosyllabiques.

Comment: La citation, lisez la bien, affirme que la liaison entre l’adverbe et le mot unis étroitement **est obligatoire** sauf dans certains cas dont ne fait pas partie l'adverbe fort. D'où il découle bien qu'elle est obligatoire.  Par ailleurs, vous dites qu'elle ne l'est pas dans ce cas et dans d'autres, mais vous n'expliquez pas pourquoi ? Est-ce simplement votre autorité face à celle de l'Académie ou avez-vous une justification à ces affirmations ? Personnellement, je dis bien "Elle est **TO**bligatoire" ou "dans **ZU**ne heure"... et pas "Elle est **ho**bligatoire dans **hu**ne heure"...

Comment: Même si je fais partie de ceux qui considèrent que l'Académie française n'est nullement une autorité, je suis entièrement d'accord avec @Eauquidort  quand il/elle écrit "Tout ce que cette citation affirme c'est que la liaison après fort n'est pas obligatoire" .

Comment: Le moins que l'on puisse dire est que cette citation de l'académie est peu claire. On est dans une section intitulée "Liaisons obligatoires" avec une négation "elle ne se pratique pas sauf…": est-ce à dire que ce qui vient après sauf est obligatoire du fait de son appartenance à cette section? Car sinon, l'inverse de "ne se pratique pas" est juste "se pratique", ce qui couvre l'obligatoire et le facultatif. J'avais accepter la réponse sans avoir lu la source et je me demande si ce n'était pas une erreur surtout au vu des autres sources fournie par @Laure.

Comment: Je suis désolé d'avoir engendré un débat "Académie contre le reste de la francophonie"!!

Comment: J'avais voulu écrire "Tout ce que cette citation affirme c'est que la liaison après *fort* n'est pas **interdite**". Ma justification me vient des études de corpus effectuées par les linguistes, voir http://www.projet-pfc.net/2010/07/27/types-de-liaisons/ et les citations sur cette page, particulièrement le segment sur "Les liaisons variables anciennement considérées comme catégoriques". D'une manière générale, l'Académie tend à définir comme obligatoire des liaisons variables mais très fréquentes (soit parmis la génération de leurs membres, comme avec *est*, soit toujours comme

Comment: après les prépositions monosyllabiques). Mais le tableau est plus complexe que ça.

Comment: Le fait que l'Académie soit ou non une autorité n'est pas affaire d'opinion, elle est une autorité en ce qui concerne la langue française, c'est même sa raison d'être : _L’Académie française, fondée en 1634 et officialisée le 29 janvier 1635, sous le règne de Louis XIII par le cardinal de Richelieu, est une institution française dont la fonction est de normaliser et de perfectionner la langue française._ https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise#R.C3.B4le_de_l.27Acad.C3.A9mie_fran.C3.A7aise . Quant à c e qu'affirme le texte, c'est bien qu'il y a une règle, des exceptions, ...

Comment: et que fort n'entre pas dans le cadre des exceptions. Mais là on risque de boucler donc je n'insisterai pas plus sur ce point. Que dans l'usage certains enchaînent avec le 'r', c'est indéniable. Mais l'intérêt de ce site il me semble est de savoir comment on parle le français selon les règles, sinon dans l'usage il y a aussi plein de gens qui vont au coiffeur...

Comment: J'ai modéré ma réponse, ce qui aidera peut-être à nous mettre d'accord :)

Comment: Concernant le coiffeur, tout dépend de ce qu'il fait exactement. Si vous avez une liaison avec lui... ;)

Comment: @Eauquidort Certes elle n'est pas interdite, mais elle n'est pas non plus obligatoire, donc tu as raison quelle que soit la formulation.

Answer (score 5):

La liaison dans *fort aimable* est facultative. C'est une liaison qui a tendance à se perdre dans le langage courant et qui fait partie d'un style de prononciation soutenu.

Quand un mot se termine par un *r* suivi des consonnes *c*, *s*, *t* ou *d*, l'enchaînement se fait avec le *r* (*une part à prendre* /paʁapʁɑ̃dʁ/), ceci pour des raisons historiques comme expliqué sur     *[Le cabinet de curiosités](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/liaison.html)*. Il y a une exception avec **fort** avec lequel on peut faire la liaison avec le **t** :
fort aimable (/fɔʁɛmabl/ ou /fɔʁtɛmabl/), fort habile (/fɔʁabil/ ou /fɔʁtabil/).

- *Le Bon usage*, 13<sup>e</sup> édition, § 42 a) :

  > Quand un mot se termine par un *r* suivi d'une consonne muette, on préfère l'enchaînement à la liaison.

  En exemple, for(t) aimable plutôt que for-t-aimable.
- > La liaison après *très* et *fort* ne s'entend que dans un style très raffiné. *Fort impressionnant* /fɔʁɛ̃pʁɛsjɔnɑ̃/.  ([*Savoir Dire: Cours de phonétique et de prononciation*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=jYdTCwAAQBAJ&dq=liaison%20apr%C3%A8s%20fort&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s),  Diane Dansereau, 2016)
- > Avec le mot *fort*, littéraire, on peut faire prononcer le *t* devant voyelle ou faire l’en­chai­ne­ment avec [ʁ] :  fort élégant (/fɔʁelegɑ̃/ ou /fɔʁtelegɑ̃/) ([*Phonétique et prononciation du français pour apprenants finnophones*](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/96.html))

Comment: Ceci devrait être la réponse acceptée. L'autre réponse s'appuie sur une interprétation erronée d'un texte de l'Académie française et n'apporte aucune autre référence.

Comment: @jlliagre  Il y a quand même une référence ... à cette réponse-ci !

Answer (score 0):

Georges Leroy,  Français, faisant part de l'usage du français dans sa Grammaire de la diction française : 
"Liaison interdite

Note : dans la suite on a noté par X l'interdiction de liaison.

Enfin, il est réputé incorrect de pratiquer une liaison : 
Après certains mots qui se terminent par deux consonnes dont une seule est sonore, tels que tard, tort, part, remords, toujours[10], nord X est, nord X ouest, il perd X un ami, je prends part X à votre deuil, à tort X et à travers ;"
Il ajoute qu'elle est facultative avec fort, qui fait pourtant partie de la même catégorie de mots.
En réalité on n'a pas besoin de faire de liaison avec fort puisque ce mot se termine par le son r.